# how to arrange into the alphabetically order if that values has html tag

Tags: laravel

I have a two values but one value are html tag how can i get those all values into the alphabetically order.
eg. `$this->ingredient->select('id', 'name')->orderby('name')->get();`

Names are:

```
<i>Bat</i>
Apple
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort collection:

```
$this->ingredient->select('id', 'name')->get()->sortBy(function ($item) {
    return strip_tags($item->name);
});
```